# How to get raw url from Owin?

Tags: c#, .net, owin

How can I get raw url from Owin (the url what was passed to HTTP request), **independently** on Owin hosting?

For instance, both http://localhost/myapp and http://localhost/myapp/ contains in `IOwinRequest.Path` the `/`. The `PathBase` contains always `/myapp` and `Uri.OriginalString` contains always http://localhost/myapp/.

(In ASP.NET I would call `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` which returns either `/myapp` or `/myapp/`.)

*Reason:* Currently, I need it to do the server side redirect to add the trailing `/` if it is missing (independently on the hosting).

Comment: Can I ask WHY you need to add the trailing `/`? IMO it shouldn't matter...

Comment: For relative urls which would point to different location if `/` is not present.

Comment: ...but there only the leading `/` is relevant: `myapp/mypage/` is relative and `/myapp/mypage/` is absolute, but `/myapp/mypage` is also absolute an points to the same location...

Comment: When some resources uses relative urls such as `foo?asasad` then if user enters `http://localhost/myapp` it will be translated into `http://localhost/foo...`.

Comment: You should add the correct prefix to the `foo` link then: Instead of `foo?asasad` the link should be `/myapp/foo?asasad` (you can use `~` and some helper methods, depending on the place where you generate the link, to resolve that correctly)...

Comment: You suggest to use to use absolute urls instead of relatives. (I cannot use `~` in static resources, moreover I think that `~` is ASP.NET specific.)

Comment: Also some relative paths come from client side AJAX requests from various libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw Url in Owin by accessing the HttpListenerContext that was used to receive the request.

```
    public static string RealUrlFromOwin(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var owincontext = ((OwinContext) request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"]);
        var env = owincontext.Environment;
        var listenerContext = (System.Net.HttpListenerContext) env["System.Net.HttpListenerContext"];
        return listenerContext.Request.RawUrl;
    }
```

This will not only recover things like a trailing / in the Url, but will also get the Url string before any decoding is applied, so you can distinguish between '!' and %21, for instance.

Comment: I expect that this will work only with HttpListener host, but not with any other host?

Comment: Agreed, but there will probably be equivalent techniques for other hosting options. Whatever listener is in use will most likely be referenced in the OwinContext.Environment collection - it's going to be a matter of finding out what key it is stored under and how to get the raw URL from it.

Comment: The question is how to do it independently on hosting. (When you are developing an owin application/library, owin is the unifying platform, you do not know all future hosting platforms.)

Comment: Ah, ok, that's not going to happen using this approach :(